# Undefined SELECT value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page I have the following SELECT:

```
<select class="span2" id="emLocality">
    <option value="_none_">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="000696" selected>USA</option>
</select>
```

Then in JavaScript I run this snippet:

```
var loc = $("emLocality").val();
console.log (loc);
console.log ($("#emLocality").val ());
```

and get the following output:

> undefined
>
> 000696

Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: Aren't you missing the hash? var loc = $("#emLocality").val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var loc = $("emLocality").val();`

To:

```
var loc = $("#emLocality").val();
```

You're missing the #.

Comment: You're right Chris, just found this. It's not my day ))